# Java creating objects within objects

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create a Pizza menu. I have 3 classes,

- PizzaBase (with get / set methods for the thickness of the base
  [either thin or deeppan])
- PizzaTopping, again with get / set methods
  for the type of topping
- Pizza, where my cost variable is stored and
  used across the 3 classes using inheritance.

As a cost variable is used for the base, the topping and the overall pizza itself.

Now my question is this, how would I go about creating a Pizza object, which in turn creates 1 base object, and a few toppings objects, each with a price?

I can work out how to calculate an overall price, I'm just a bit stuck creating objects within objects.

```
 public class PizzaTopping extends Pizza{

private String topping;




public String getTopping(){
    return this.topping; 
}

public void setTopping( String topping ){
    this.topping = topping;

    }

}



   public class PizzaBase extends Pizza{

  private String base;  


    public void setBase( String base ){
    this.base = base;
    }

    public String getBase(){
        return this.base;
    }




 }




 public class Pizza {
private double cost;

public void setCost( double cost ){
    this.cost = Math.abs(cost);
}
public double getCost(){
    return this.cost; 
}


public void makingPizza(){
    PizzaBase b = new PizzaBase();



}

 }
```

Comment: Why should `PizzaTopping` extend `Pizza`? A `Pizza` is *composed* of `PizzaTopping`s; a `PizzaTopping` is not a `Pizza` itself. I would rethink the object model.

Comment: Yea since asking this question I have got rid of the inheritance aspect.. each class now has its own cost property. However I'm still struggling with creating objects within objects

Comment: Well you already have an object within an object, `String topping`. It's not really any more special than that.

Comment: I would make an interface for your "pricing" to start.  This way, you can use polymorphism and impress your teacher.  Second, I don't see any contructors, just getters/setters.  I would have a constructor on Pizza that took an array/list of PizzaTopings and a PizzaBase.  This constructor would then set all the approriate items on itself (encapsulation, teachers love that too).  The PizzaToppings and PizzaBase classes probably also need some sort of constructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the Pizza class with CostableItem class:

```
public class CostableItem {
 private double cost;

 public void setCost( double cost ){
    this.cost = Math.abs(cost);
 }
 public double getCost(){
    return this.cost; 
 }
}
```

Then extend it in both toppings and base:

```
public class PizzaBase extends CostableItem {...}
public class PizzaTopping extends CostableItem {...}
```

After that create a class called Pizza that has one base and multiple toppings:

```
public class Pizza{
 private PizzaBase base;
 private ArrayList<PizzaToppings> toppings;
 //..
}
```

Comment: It would be better to make `CostableItem` an interface.

Comment: I think so too, just answering his question about how to create a object inside a object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inheritance for this at all. At the most you might need an interface. So I would design it this way:

```
public interface PricedItem {
   double getCost(); //double is suitable for our purposes
}
```

Since you want to calculate cost, everything that is a priced item should have a `getCost()` method. This will apply to your `PizzaTopping`, `PizzaBase`, and `Pizza` class:

```
public class PizzaTopping implements PricedItem

    private String name;
    private double cost;

    public PizzaTopping(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

More or less the same thing for `PizzaBase`:

```
public class PizzaBase implements PricedItem {

    private double cost;

    ...

}
```

Your `Pizza` class will also implement `PricedItem`. But what is also important is that you will have a collection of `PizzaTopping` instances; there is no inheritance here!

```
public class Pizza implements PricedItem {

   private double cost;
   private PizzaBase base;
   private List<PizzaTopping> toppings;

   public Pizza(double cost, PizzaBase base) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.base = base;
        toppings = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();
   }

   ...

   public void addTopping(PizzaTopping topping) {
       //left as an exercise to the reader :)
   }

   @Override
   public double getCost() {
        //this is left as an exercise to the reader :)

        return totalCost;
   }  
}
```